# What happened to CFFI-UNIX?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clim

My ultimate goal here is to get the system FLEXI-TRIVIAL-DIRED (http://common-lisp.net/project/ftd/) to compile, which I'm having trouble with because I can't find one of the required packages, CFFI-UNIX anywhere.

Does anyone know what happened to it, why it originally existed, if it was merged into another project, why this was, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system used to "*provide a portable interface to Unix functionality, with a focus on networking*". Looking at the source of FTD, you can see it calling  `cffi-unix::getgrgid`. This functionallity is now provided (superseded) by [osicat](https://github.com/osicat/osicat/blob/master/posix/unix.lisp#L685).